# How to Calculate single-vector Dot Product using SSE intrinsic functions in C

Tags: c, optimization, vectorization, sse, simd

I am trying to multiply two vectors together where each element of one vector is multiplied by the element in the same index at the other vector.  I then want to sum all the elements of the resulting vector to obtain one number.  For instance, the calculation would look like this for the vectors {1,2,3,4} and {5,6,7,8}:

```
1*5 + 2*6 + 3*7 + 4*8
```

Essentially, I am taking the dot product of the two vectors.  I know there is an SSE command to do this, but the command doesn't have an intrinsic function associated with it.  At this point, I don't want to write inline assembly in my C code, so I want to use only intrinsic functions.  This seems like a common calculation so I am surprised by myself that I couldn't find the answer on Google.

Note:  I am optimizing for a specific micro architecture which supports up to SSE 4.2.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**If you're doing a dot-product of longer vectors, use multiply and regular `_mm_add_ps` (or FMA) inside the inner loop.**  Save the horizontal sum until the end.

---

But if you are doing a dot product of just a single pair of SIMD vectors:

GCC (at least version 4.3) includes `<smmintrin.h>` with SSE4.1 level intrinsics, including the single and double-precision dot products:

```
_mm_dp_ps (__m128 __X, __m128 __Y, const int __M);
_mm_dp_pd (__m128d __X, __m128d __Y, const int __M);
```

On Intel mainstream CPUs (not Atom/Silvermont) these are somewhat faster than doing it manually with multiple instructions.

But on AMD (including Ryzen), `dpps` is significantly slower.  (See [Agner Fog's instruction tables](https://agner.org/optimize/))

---

As a fallback for older processors, you can use this algorithm to create the dot product of the vectors `a` and `b`:

```
__m128 r1 = _mm_mul_ps(a, b);
```

and then horizontal sum `r1` using [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86/35270026#35270026) (see there for a commented version of this, and why it's faster.)

```
__m128 shuf   = _mm_shuffle_ps(r1, r1, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 3, 0, 1));
__m128 sums   = _mm_add_ps(r1, shuf);
shuf          = _mm_movehl_ps(shuf, sums);
sums          = _mm_add_ss(sums, shuf);
float result =  _mm_cvtss_f32(sums);
```

A slow alternative costs 2 shuffles per `hadd`, which will easily bottleneck on shuffle throughput, especially on Intel CPUs.

```
r2 = _mm_hadd_ps(r1, r1);
r3 = _mm_hadd_ps(r2, r2);
_mm_store_ss(&result, r3);
```

Comment: As a note, I would like to point out that calculating the Dot product using the _dp_ intrinsic is slower than doing it the second way.

Comment: @SergueiFedorov that depends entirely on your hardware, there is no global case that it is slower.

Comment: I think there are better ways for horizontal sum than using `_mm_hadd_ps`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026/195787.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say the fastest SSE method would be:

```
static inline float CalcDotProductSse(__m128 x, __m128 y) {
    __m128 mulRes, shufReg, sumsReg;
    mulRes = _mm_mul_ps(x, y);

    // Calculates the sum of SSE Register - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026/195787
    shufReg = _mm_movehdup_ps(mulRes);        // Broadcast elements 3,1 to 2,0
    sumsReg = _mm_add_ps(mulRes, shufReg);
    shufReg = _mm_movehl_ps(shufReg, sumsReg); // High Half -> Low Half
    sumsReg = _mm_add_ss(sumsReg, shufReg);
    return  _mm_cvtss_f32(sumsReg); // Result in the lower part of the SSE Register
}
```

I followed - [Fastest Way to Do Horizontal Float Vector Sum On x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764).

Comment: Great find, the hadd instructions expand to several uops.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this and compiled it with `gcc -O3 -S -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 sse.c`

```
void f(int * __restrict__ a, int * __restrict__ b, int * __restrict__ c, int * __restrict__ d,
       int * __restrict__ e, int * __restrict__ f, int * __restrict__ g, int * __restrict__ h,
       int * __restrict__ o)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        o[i] = a[i]*e[i] + b[i]*f[i] + c[i]*g[i] + d[i]*h[i];
}
```

And GCC 4.3.0 auto-vectorized it:

```
sse.c:5: note: LOOP VECTORIZED.
sse.c:2: note: vectorized 1 loops in function.
```

However, it would only do that if I used a loop with enough iterations -- otherwise the verbose output would clarify that vectorization was unprofitable or the loop was too small.  Without the `__restrict__` keywords it has to generate separate, non-vectorized versions to deal with cases where the output `o` may point into one of the inputs.

I would paste the instructions as an example, but since part of the vectorization unrolled the loop it's not very readable.

Comment: I think he meant something else. Like 2 arrays of 4 elements each. What you do here is something else. Something like dot product of array of vectors.

Answer (score 3):

There is an article by Intel [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/use-intriniscs/) which touches on dot-product implementations.